# ELSE IF statement that returns specific values

Tags: sql-server

Can any one help with this query, I am new to mssql and i am trying to return a specific value dependant on the value returned in the tblWJC.WJCStatusID row. so for example if the WJCStatusID is >2 but <4 I want to return "in production"

SQL QUERY

```
SELECT tblWJCItem.AddedDescription, 
tblWJC.WJCPrefix + Convert(Varchar(10),tblWJC.WJCNo) AS OurRef, 
tblWJCItem.MaterialName, tblStockFamily.StockFamily, 
tblWJCItem.WeightToSend, 
tblWJC.DateCreated,
tblWJC.WJCStatusID
FROM tblWJC 
INNER JOIN tblWJCItem ON tblWJC.WJCID = tblWJCItem.WJCID 
INNER JOIN tblStockFamily ON tblWJCItem.ProductFamilyID = tblStockFamily.StockFamilyID
IF tblWJC.WJCStatusID < 2 PRINT 'Pre Production'
ELSE IF tblWJC.WJCStatusID < 4 PRINT 'In Production'
ELSE IF tblWJC.WJCStatusID > 4 PRINT 'Ready To Ship'
ELSE PRINT 'Awaiting Lab Results';
```

I have also tried the following clauses:

```
IF (tblWJC.WJCStatusID) < 2 THEN  'Pre Production'
ELSE IF (tblWJC.WJCStatusID) < 4 THEN 'In Production'
ELSE IF (tblWJC.WJCStatusID) > 4 THEN 'Ready To Ship'
ELSE 'Awaiting Lab Results';
```

I am using MSSQL and I can't seem to get this to work correctly, as I said I am new to this so I may be doing something very basic wrong. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be greatful.

Comment: IF ELSE is used to control flow of statements. It is NOT used to control logic within a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement ([info here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)). There are a few variations you can use but the `CaseExample` column below does what you are seemingly trying to accomplish.

```
SELECT tblWJCItem.AddedDescription, 
tblWJC.WJCPrefix + Convert(Varchar(10),tblWJC.WJCNo) AS OurRef, 
tblWJCItem.MaterialName, tblStockFamily.StockFamily, 
tblWJCItem.WeightToSend, 
tblWJC.DateCreated,
tblWJC.WJCStatusID,

CASE WHEN tblWJC.WJCStatusID < 2 THEN 'Pre Production'
     WHEN tblWJC.WJCStatusID < 4 THEN 'In Production'
     WHEN tblWJC.WJCStatusID > 4 THEN 'Ready To Ship'
     ELSE 'Awaiting Lab Results' -- This would only be hit when tblWJC.WJCStatusID is NULL
     END
  AS CaseExample

FROM tblWJC 
INNER JOIN tblWJCItem ON tblWJC.WJCID = tblWJCItem.WJCID 
INNER JOIN tblStockFamily ON tblWJCItem.ProductFamilyID = tblStockFamily.StockFamilyID
```

Comment: Thanks Jason worked perfectly will accept your answer once I can